# Django application to manage a small Inventory

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have created a very small Django application to manage a very small Inventory.

My **models.py** code is:

```
class Inventory(models.Model):
    account = models.ForeignKey(
        "accounts.Account", on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=False, blank=False
    )


class InventoryProduct(models.Model):
    inventory = models.ForeignKey("Inventory", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sku = models.ForeignKey(
        "products.SKU", on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=False, blank=False
    )
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        default=0
    ) 


class Transaction(models.Model):
    IN = 1
    OUT = 0
    TYPE_CHOICES = (
        (IN, "Incoming"),  # Carico / Entrata
        (OUT, "Outgoing"),  # Scarico / Uscita
    )
    inventory = models.ForeignKey("Inventory", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    transferred_to = models.ForeignKey(
        "Inventory", on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True
    )
    code = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4)
    transaction_type = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        choices=TYPE_CHOICES, default=IN
    )
    transaction_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    notes = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)


class TransactionItem(models.Model):
    transaction = models.ForeignKey("Transaction", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    item = models.ForeignKey("InventoryProduct", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        self.item.quantity += self.quantity
        self.item.save()
```

The code is quite explanatory, I basically have an **Inventory** per account and the **Inventory** has products that I add in the related model **InventoryItem**. Each product in **InventoryItem** has a quantity that will be updated during a **Transaction**.

A Transaction has a type IN/OUT to understand if i have to add or remove Items from the Inventory. Lastly, as you can surelly understand the TransactionItem has all the Items with the quantity (to add or remove) inside a Transaction.

It is quite simply, I really appreciate your opinion if i can improve the modelling somehow.

My questions are:

1. Add a way to transfer products from an Inventory to another (i think i need an OUT Transaction and then an IN Transaction), but how can I keep track of this "movement" from an Inventory to another? I would like to save from what Inventory the products are coming from.
2. This question is also related to the first one. Products can be added to an Inventory from an **Order** or by a transfer from another Inventory. How can I also include the **Order** "concept"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. Tracking Transfers Between Inventories**

To keep track of where the products are coming from, you might consider adding a *transferred_from* field as well.
This will allow you to create a direct link between the source and destination inventories for each transfer.

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    # Existing fields...
    transferred_from = models.ForeignKey(
        "Inventory", related_name="transferred_from_transactions", on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True
    )
    transferred_to = models.ForeignKey(
        "Inventory", related_name="transferred_to_transactions", on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True
    )
```

Example Query:

```
# Assuming 'last_transaction' is a Transaction instance
last_transaction = Transaction.objects.last()

# To find out where the product came from
if last_transaction.transferred_from:
    source_inventory = last_transaction.transferred_from
    print(f"Product came from Inventory ID: {source_inventory.id}")
else:
    print("This product did not come from another inventory.")
```

**2. Including the Order Concept**

Add new model: Order and OrderItem Models

```
class Order(models.Model):
    order_code = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    order_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    # Additional fields as needed

class OrderItem(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sku = models.ForeignKey("products.SKU", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
```

Next, add a reference to an Order in your Transaction model:

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    # Existing fields...
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True, related_name="transactions")
```

Example Usage:

```
# Assuming 'some_transaction' is a Transaction instance
some_transaction = Transaction.objects.select_related('order', 'transferred_from').last()

# Check if the transaction is linked to an order
if some_transaction.order:
    print(f"Transaction linked to Order ID: {some_transaction.order.id}")

# Check where the products came from
if some_transaction.transferred_from:
    print(f"Products transferred from Inventory ID: {some_transaction.transferred_from.id}")
else:
    print("Products were not transferred from another inventory.")
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello @chheee thank you for your answer. I think that Order implementation is a bit redoundant, no? It is very similar to InventoryProduct....

Comment: Hi @Dail, look like my design is a little bit confuse between InventoryProduct and OrderItem. so, let clarify

the model I've introduced is aim to handle behavior of order-transaction.

Order model: should captures information of a customer and other order behavior such as customer_id, order_date, order_status, total_amout ...
OrderItem: breaks down the order into the individual products,  including their price, quantity, and any discounts applied.

Answer (score 0):

I would remove 'transaction_type', and rename 'inventory' and 'transfer_to' to something like 'source_inventory' and 'target_inventory'. So transfer from one inventory to another would be a single Transaction. IN transactions for given inventory are those where that given inventory is a target_inventory for transaction, and OUT transactions are those where it is source_inventory.